# Can the process gluon + gluon $\rightarrow$ 2 Higgs proceed in the following way in the standard model?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs, quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

At order $g_s^2$, usually only a triangle quark loop and box diagram are considered, I was wondering, is there some reason that excludes these diagrams from the possible standard model channels?

[image: loop to higgs]

[image]

Comment: Your first diagram violates color conservation: a color gluon cannot go to a colorless Higgs via a top loop! Your second one, twisted around, would be the normal "triangle" diagram, except emitting a further Higgs off the top line, requiring much higher energy... *much* ...

Comment: Thank you, I understand about the first diagram. About the second, it is not the same as a triangle loop diagram, it is similar  to the box diagram for Higgs pair creation from gluons, however, the order of the vertices is changed ggHH $\rightarrow$ gHgH.

Comment: It is always understood in these diagrams that the ones with permitted order are always implied!